# Difference between β0 and u

Tags: econometrics

In the book *Introductory Econometrics: A modern approach*, it explains that u is the unobservable factors and β0 is the constant. Since both of them are constants (if I'm not mistaken), what is the difference between them?

Comment: Wooldridge often supress the individual index hence in the equation $y_i = \beta_0 + u_i$ he could write $y = \beta_0 + u$ leaving it implicit that the unobserved $u$ varies - is not constant - across individuals (sampling units).

Comment: @JesperHybel, thanks for the comment. This is what I understand from what you shared:

For every individual i the u is going to be different, but the β0 is going to be the same. Is that correct?

Also, what does the u measure and what does the β0 measure?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes every individual will have their own particular realization $u_i$. $\beta_0$ has the same units as your dependent variable $y$ and it is "affecting" all individuals $i$ in the sample .. it is an additive effect to the expected value of $y$.

Comment: @JesperHybel  Does "it is "affecting" all individuals i in the sample" mean $\beta_0$ is not "affecting" the individuals who are not in the sample?

Comment: No, the equation is assumed to hold for the entire population. So a more precise statement could be $\forall i \in P: y_i = \beta_0 + u_i$ with $P$ being the population.